# How to share a private file between a widget and an activity?

Tags: java, android, file, widget

I know I can use getFilesDir() in an activity and a filename to save/read a file. However, when I try to call getFilesDir() from within the widget, I get an error. I would like to be able to access the same text file both from the widget and from the activity.

What is the simplest way to achieve that?

Comment: show ur code and as well ur stack ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) for this purpose. Here's a short example:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets(); 
String[] files = assetManager.list("Files");
InputStream input = assetManager.open("helloworld.txt");
int size = input.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
input.read(buffer);
input.close();
String text = new String(buffer);
```

**Update:** Sorry, forgot that you wanted this for use in the widget. You may try this code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12244647/1292652):

```
InputStream is = mContext.getAssets().open(someFile);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"UTF-8"));
```

**Warning:** Do not use this code as is. You should use proper code which catches errors and edge cases.

Comment: Silly me! I just realized onUpdate gets passed a Context... Your answer made me realize that when I thought "well, where do I grab an mContext from?" Thanks!!! Works just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getFilesDir()` from any `Context`So you can Save\Read your file from [Application](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html&ei=3OlNUZjxCunR0QX6lIH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHlOiaTSPSHtnZxHDzwp7YJYgf5OA&sig2=1nd1_BV9FW2SgENfuWlP3Q&bvm=bv.44158598,d.d2k).

**Edit:**

You have to extend a Class from [Application](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html&ei=3OlNUZjxCunR0QX6lIH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHlOiaTSPSHtnZxHDzwp7YJYgf5OA&sig2=1nd1_BV9FW2SgENfuWlP3Q&bvm=bv.44158598,d.d2k) and use it's context:

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Then in `manifest` of your App,set `name` property of `Application` tag with name of that class,for example:

```
android:name="App"
```

Note: App is name of that class that extends [Application](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html&ei=3OlNUZjxCunR0QX6lIH4BQ&usg=AFQjCNHlOiaTSPSHtnZxHDzwp7YJYgf5OA&sig2=1nd1_BV9FW2SgENfuWlP3Q&bvm=bv.44158598,d.d2k).

Now you can use it's context to do save\read:

```
App.getContext().getFilesDir();
```

Comment: I just tried... when using "Context context = getApplicationContext();", I get "... is undefined for the type widget". What am I missing out?